# Move selection down a row and change font color from red to black when there is a change to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a vba code that works great to keep the selection of one sheet on the same cell when there is a change.

Now, i need a vba code to Move selection down a row and change font color from red to black in another sheet (sheet1 column A) when there is that same change.

Current code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A4")) Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Me.Range("A5").Value = Target.Value
Target.Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

So, when there is a change to Sheet7 cell A4, i need the selection in Sheet1 Column A to drop one row and change the font color from RED to BLACK.Please help!!

Comment: What have you tried? Wouldn't you just need a line in there saying something like `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Target.row).Offset(1,0).Font.Color = RGB(0,0,0)`?  ...what sheet did you put this `Worksheet_Change()` event in?

Comment: Hi Bruce. this did not work for me.  the worksheet change is in my Sheet7. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it should be something like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A4")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Me.Range("A5").Value = Target.Value
    Target.Select
    Sheet1.Range("A" & Target.row + 1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is only working one time. After every change, it should move down one row, creating a list in the end. any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: @lstrick - It's unclear - do you want the color to move down one cell *regardless* of the `Target` cell in `Sheet7`?

Comment: That's the question .... It wasn't clear in the first question.  If You select the same cell in Sheet7, you want the black cells in sheet1 to increment down by one more, not just by one row?

Comment: When the target cell changes (it changes because things are getting scanned into excel) it will pull the the number in the target A4 to another sheet. i need these numbers scanned from A4 to form a list elsewhere

Comment: fully put, numbers get scanned into excel over and over again. the original VBA code keeps the cell selection in place when there is a change to save time for the person scanning. but now, we want to form a list of all "Yes" products (i tell if it is yes based on the output in C4.) these "yes" products, i need to be entered into a list. i am struggling to make this a continuous process when the scanner does not need to stop.

Comment: So A4 changes when the user scans something, and you just want to keep a list of everything that was scanned into A4.  Is that right?  Do you want that list to be in Sheet1 column A?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.  Again, untested.  But I commented out the color change in case the text in Sheet1 Column A is black.  You wouldn't be able to see the text if it is.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A4")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Me.Range("A5").Value = Target.Value
        Target.Select
        Sheet1.Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Value = Target.Value
'        Sheet1.Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Interior.Color = vbBlack
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```